# How do you insert a 2D List into a tkinter Text widget without producing {} square brackets

Tags: python, string, tkinter, text, formatting

I am trying to Insert a 2D List into my tkinter Text widget.

```
textOrder.insert(tk.INSERT,"Main\n")
textOrder.insert(tk.INSERT,["3","The""\n"])
textOrder.insert(tk.INSERT,"Side\n")
textOrder.insert(tk.INSERT,"Drink\n")
```

However this yields {} around the word The as seen below:

[image: Text Widget]

I know I could remove the {} by string formatting, but is there a way of avoiding these {} in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know I could remove the {} by string formatting, but is there a way of avoiding these {} in the first place?

No, there is not. It is your responsibility to pass strings into the `insert` method.

If you don't explicitly convert values to strings before calling `insert`, the curly braces is the result of the implicit conversion. If you don't like the implicit conversion, you must do an explicit conversion.